# If someone is wrongfully chasing a child and the child knocks into something and is injured is the person that is pursuing the child responsible?

Tags: criminal-law, civil-law, new-york-state, children

If two adults set out to pursue a child that didn't do anything wrong but was in the company of other children one of of whom may have done something, and the child flees and in being pursued trips and falls and injures himself, are the adults criminally or civilly liable?
For this question, I have in mind the situation that can be seen in this video clip:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5f5G6sUVaXE

Comment: Surely the crime is tackling the child.  That would be assault, or actual bodily harm (depending where the injuries were sustained) in the UK.

Comment: Note that the partial surveillance video was sent to the press [by the defense](https://newyork.cbslocal.com/2020/11/28/long-island-dentists-charged-chasing-teen/). We don't know what else the prosecution has for evidence.

Comment: I suspect the charges might have been dropped though, since this news is from Nov 2020 and I can't find any press follow-up.

Comment: This question is asking what law applies in a specific situation. It is not asking what do do, or what options a party has. There is no indication that the poster is in any way involved in the situation. This is not a request for specific legal advice under this site's policy, and should not be closed as such.

Comment: I've tagged with "children" since the story says "Napoli and Gambella are both charged with endangering the welfare of a child, plus a reckless driving charge for Napoli."

Comment: I can assure you I am not involved in any way with this case. For my particular interest here, I observed in the comments in the YouTube page of this video that much is being made of the fact that in the video of the incident the child strikes an object ( I think a pot) which causes him to fall, rather than falling by a contact with the adult. In terms of my common sense however, I reason that the child would not have fallen if he were not being pursued by the adult. I feel tackling includes running someone down. What would be the legal consensus on this? How would it be decided?

Comment: If the prosecution believed he actually tackled him, they might have charged with assault instead of ["endangering the welfare of a child"](https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/laws/PEN/260.10).

Comment: I'm not able to watch the video but this could be a civil liability on the adult's part, though it does involve a lot of factors your scenario leaves to assumption, such as the nature of why the adult was chasing the kid, the relationship between the adult and child and the severity of the injuries.

Answer (score 4):

If the pursuit is unlawful (which it almost always is except for police) and the pursued suffers harm in fleeing from the pursuer, then the pursuer is responsible both criminally and civilly.

Being pursued would put a person in fear of harm: that’s the criteria for assault so the act of pursuing someone without lawful cause is a crime. Self-defence ceases to be a defence when the other person is running away - even if they are carrying your TV. You can use reasonable force to effect an arrest but a pursuit is not likely to be reasonable if it is of any significant distance or involves vehicles. Police pursuits are strictly limited and police have been successfully sued when they exceed those limits and harm comes to the pursued.

If the pursed dies, pursuers can and have been convicted of murder or manslaughter.